# Block Round Off using decimal pipe in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

Using angular 4,

```
{{31.94 | number:'1.0-0'}}
```

Output: 32

Any idea, how to block the round off. Expecting the result is 31

Answer (score 7):

You need to create your custom pipe as DecimalPipe doesn't provide any floor feature. Plus you can add your decimal pipe in it.
**Your Custom Pipe:**

```
@Pipe({name: 'floor'})
export class FloorPipe implements PipeTransform {
    /**
     *
     * @param value
     * @returns {number}
     */
    transform(value: number): number {
        return Math.floor(value);
    }
}
```

**Use in template as:**

```
  <span>{{ yournumber | floor | your_decimal_pipe }}</span>
```

Comment: It will just floor the value, but I will be missing the comma (whatever decimal pipe doing) in case of using 1999.99, it will not gives us 1,999

Comment: You can use multiple pipes then {{ yournumber | floor | your_decimal_pipe }}

Comment: Yes, I can write a custom pipe to do the work (floor value, comma formatted etc.) but just wanted to confirm if angular decimal pipe already have the config or not.

Comment: No, they don't.

Comment: If you find your solution from this you can mark it correct :)

Comment: I also suggest using this lib  https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/. You use it within your custom pipe so that you get the rounding that you want.

Answer (score 2):

## your.component.ts

```
import { Component, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({name: 'DecimalPipe'})
export class NumNotRoundPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number): number {
    var num1 = Math.floor(value * 100) / 100;
    return num1;
  }
}
```

## your.module.ts

```
import {NumNotRoundPipe} from './your.component'

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    ],
    declarations: [
        NumNotRoundPipe
    ],
    entryComponents: [

    ],
    providers: [

    ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
```

## your.component.html

```
<span>{{yourNumber | DecimalPipe:'1.2-2'}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not need an extra custom pipe. Output is a string and there are plenty of string pipes. You might truncate like this :

```
{{31.94 | slice:0:2}}
//Output : 31
```

Would achieve your desired output in that specific case.

```
{{1.94 | number:'2.2-2' | slice:0:2}}
//Output : 01
```

You'll still want to use custom pipe for now if you don't want padding 0.

Comment: What about 0.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

When only 'round' is available, you can simulate 'floor' by substracting 0.5 to the value.

```
{{31.94 - 0.5 | number:'1.0-0'}}
```

If your value can be below 0.5, in order to avoid printing "-1", you'd have to write:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="myVal >= 0.5">{{ myVal - 0.5 | number:'1.0-0' }}></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="myVal < 0.5">0</ng-container>
```

Answer (score -2):

In your module file:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
```

Add it to imports array:

```
imports [
   CommonModule
]
```

Then use:

```
{{31.94 | number:'1.0-0'}} 
// It will display 31
```