# Decimal Pipe in Angular 2 - No Decimal Places WITHOUT Rounding

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I currently use this pipe `{{ person.ageInDays/7 | number:'1.0-0' }}` to show a person's age in week which seems not working accurately! It rounds the number up sometimes.

For example for an infant with 257 days old it should be 36 weeks and and 5 days whereas the result which is 37 weeks and 5 days!

Comment: The answer is Custom Pipes. Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416447/block-round-off-using-decimal-pipe-in-angular-4?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the [angular doc](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#description), it clearly mentions the behavior of number pipe.

> If no parameters are specified, the function rounds off to the nearest
>   value using this rounding method. The behavior differs from that of
>   the JavaScript Math.round() function. In the following case for
>   example, the pipe rounds down where Math.round() rounds up

You would have to create a custom pipe in your case

```
@Pipe({name: 'daystoweek'})
export class DaysToWeekPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: number): number {
        return Math.floor(value);
    }
}
```

Use that custom pipe in your code

```
{{ numbervalue | daystoweek}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Decimal JS

```
import Decimal from "decimal.js";

let r: Decimal.Rounding = Decimal.ROUND_UP;
let c: Decimal.Configuration = {rounding: r };
Decimal.set(c);
let v: Decimal.Value = "12345.6789";
let d: Decimal = new Decimal(v);

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
  <div>
    ${d.toFixed(3)}
  </div>`
```