# Angular Number pipe changing value

Tags: angular5

I'm creating a new textbox to accept numbers with decimals in my web application using Angular 5. But I see that Angular is changing one particular number which is 31.74 to 31.73. How to keep my current number?

My application is built using Asp.Net MVC 5, Angular 5, C#, SQL Database.

```
<input name="txtTEST" type="text" style="width: 120px; text-align: right;" maxlength="15" tabindex="1" [disabled]="!isEnableTest" [ngModel]="test|number:'1.2-2'" (ngModelChange)="ModelOnChange($event, 'tst')" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}" />
```

I expect the output of 31.74 to be 31.74. But the actual output is 31.73.

-------Solved-------

I'm dividing 31.74 by 100 (which should give me 0.3174) in Angular and it becomes 0.31739999. This number is rounded to 31.73 when I pass it to my C# code.

So in Angular instead of dividing by 100 I changed the code to:

```
k.aTest = (this.test * 100) / 10000;
```

And problem solved.

-------------STILL THIS ISSUE IS THERE-------
It is randomly happening based on numbers.

Comment: Do you enter 31.74 and it changes to 31.73?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416447/block-round-off-using-decimal-pipe-in-angular-4

Comment: Hi Vega, yes I enter 31.74 and it changes to 31.73